# Reading from files in C++

Tags: c++, user-input

A file contains a list of telephone numbers in the following form :

```
John            23456
Ahmed        9876
Joe 4568
```

The names contain only word and the names and telephone numbers are separated by white spaces. Write a program to read the file and output the list in two columns. The names should be left-justified and the numbers right-justified.

I was able to remove whitespace and display it but cannot align it in output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    fstream file,f2;
    file.open("list.txt",ios::in|ios::out);
    f2.open("abcd.txt",ios::out);
    file.seekg(0);

    char ch,ch1;
    file.get(ch);

    while(file)
    {
        ch1 = ch;
        file.get(ch);

        if( ch == ' ' && ch1 != ' ')
        {
            f2.put(ch1);
            f2.put(' ');
        }

        if(ch != ' ' && ch1 != ' ')
            f2.put(ch1);
    }

    file.close();
    f2.close();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework assignment.

Comment: I bet you're coming from C.

Comment: Please format your code properly next time, and use your spacebar for heavens sake.

Comment: `<iostream.h>`? I'd demand my money back!

Comment: Tis not C++. This code is infested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest straightforward (no paranoid input format checking):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("list.txt");

    std::string name; int val;
    while (ifs >> name >> val)
    {
        std::cout << std::left  << std::setw(30) << name << 
                     std::right << std::setw(12) << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
John                                 23456
Ahmed                                 9876
Joe                                   4568
```

Comment: Can you please explain me the working of
while (ifs >> name >> val) ?
How's the name and number assigned to name and val?

Comment: The `>>` operator overload is known as 'stream extraction operator` and is defined for all common builtin types (like double, int, string). The operator returns the original stream. The test for success (`if (ifs)`) works because of a conversion to a boolean type that results in false if extraction failed. Lastly, by default C++ ifstream will have the `std::ios::skipws` flag set, which is why you don't need to bother skipping spaces or newlines manually. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the appropriate flags on your output stream (`f2` is the output stream in your case).
See the following article:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/width/

For your example, replace `cout` with `f2` since they're both output streams inheriting from `ios_base`.